# Saving a MemoryStream to a FileStream as ASCII

Tags: c#, filestream, memorystream

I have a memory stream that writes to a file stream.  I need to be change the code below to save the memory stream as ASCII.

```
 using (var ms = new memoryStream)
    {
       //...DownloadFile(file, ms);
       using (var fs = File.Create(file))
       {
           ms.WriteTo(fs);
       }
    }
```

Comment: A MemoryStream has no notion of encoding since it could represent anything. If the content you are downloading is ASCII, it will be saved as ASCII. Are you trying to convert the encoding?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to convert a binary stream that I am getting from an SFTP download into a ASCII.  I have no way of setting the download as ASCII.

Comment: If you need to convert to ASCII you need to know what encoding it was before to correctly convert it.

Comment: A binary stream is, by definition, an encoding of whatever data the stream contains. In your case this is text, which was encoded at/by the SFTP server. Therefore you only need to save the binary stream directly to a file, as per Alberto's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllBytes(file, ms.ToArray())
```

Comment: does this imply an ASCII conversion?